# Prevent child div from clipping while parent is overflow:auto (because of its dynamic content)

Tags: html, css

I've got problem with simple HTML and CSS code.
I need to make one div to be "out of" parent div, while other ones are inside of parent, and they have to stretch it vertically.

```css
#parent{
  width:80%;
  min-height:50px;
  background:red;
  }
.child{
  width:20%;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:-5%;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  }
.child-b{
width:40%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child-b">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor sit amet purus nec venenatis. Integer maximus, nisi et pretium convallis, erat metus malesuada lorem, nec porttitor leo felis sollicitudin dolor.
  </div>
  <div class="child-b">
  Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent height needs to be dynamic, equal to child-b.
Child has to be 100% of parent div and needs to be on minus margin left, to be "out of parent visually".

It has to look like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use flex instead of float. This will avoid you the use of `oveflow:auto` to fix the floating issue and you can easily align your element and make all of them same height. Then use negative margin on the div you want to make outisde like you already did.

```css
#parent {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right:5px;
  background:blue;
}

.child-b {
  flex: 50%;
  padding:10px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child-b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor sit amet purus nec venenatis. Integer maximus, nisi et pretium convallis, erat metus malesuada lorem, nec porttitor leo felis sollicitudin dolor.
  </div>
  <div class="child-b">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about that flex makes div automatically overflowed.

Comment: @Calix well it's not only about flex ... but we can say that everything flow normally (flex, block, inline-block, grid) but floating not, that's overflow is only needed for float ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `display:flex`;

```
#parent{
  width:80%;
  min-height:50px;
  background:red;
  display: flex;
  align-item:center;
  }
```

For better understanding of flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox